# Developer Console : Log Columns > Where do values come from for 'Application' column?

Tags: developer-console

Typically, the Application column's value in the Developer Console's log tab = `Unknown`.

Is is possible to use it to display the apex class name that originated the logging (or another arbitrary value)?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to use it to display the apex class name that originated the logging (or another arbitrary value)?

No.

That field is set at the start of the transaction in the [Client Headers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.htm). It is up to each application developer to set the appropriate header, though not all developers do this.

Comment: Thank you; I find locating my debug statements in logs is tiresome and could be much quicker.

Comment: @Shaun You can set up Trace Flags to debug specific classes. This can help reduce the number of logs generated and the size of those logs.